# Menu Icon doesn't appear in my Android menu

Tags: android, cordova, menu, contextmenu

In my app menu icon is not displaying, For me at present text/string is displaying but i need icon/image intent of text. Also try using xml format menu calling.

- Android version is ver_4
- cordova_2.5.0
- Image/Icon size=32*32

testapp.java

```
 package com.example.testapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class testapp extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
 }

private static final int HOME = 0;
private static final int SETTINGS = 1;
private static final int HELP = 2;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, HOME, 0, "Home")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_home) 
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    menu.add(0, SETTINGS, 0, "Settings")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_settings)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    menu.add(0, HELP, 0, "Help")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_help)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return true;


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case HOME:
             // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, testapp.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case SETTINGS:
             this.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
            return true;
        case HELP:
            this.appView.sendJavascript("navigator.notification.alert('No help')");
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

My testapp.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_home"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
      android:title="Home" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
      android:title="Settings" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_help"
      android:title="Help" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be... You should remove: android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in AndroidManifest.xml

Or edit: android:theme="@android:style/Theme"